# Can't run react native app using usb debugging

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, usb-debugging

I'm trying to run react native app on my mobile but it fails although it working perfectly on the emulator. This is the error appears after running **react-native run-android**:

```
BUILD FAILED in 11s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Unable to install C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\rn-playground\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
```

Comment: can you show the entire error?

Comment: Try cleaning cache using "Projecy>android>./gradlew clean" then use "sudo react-native run-android" command